# Node/Folder Deletion History - Adobe AEM/CQ

Tags: adobe, aem

We have a situation, where a node (It was a client lib folder) got deleted from AEM repository, not sure which user did this. I was looking, if AEM stores Node/Folder deletion history somewhere, so that we can identify, who had taken action of deleting the node.

Few options I tried/was thinking of

1. Tried to check logs, if there some info, but on creation or deletion of node, didn't see any logs with node name
2. Have a content change listener on repo, but that will load AEM un-necessarily. Also this will not give information on nodes which were deleted before listener was registered.

Is there a audit log or history stored for deleted nodes in AEM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes AEM can store and provide audit log entries for WCM events like e.g. page modifications. 
But it requires the audit logger to be enabled (through the configuration admin console /system/console/configMgr).

If this is the case then check either the audit.log file in your logs directory or the audit records below /var/audit

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. Verified this, after audit log level is changed to DEBUG, I could see entries for node creation and deletion. But if this was not turned on (like in my case), there is no way to get information right?

Comment: Exactly, if it is not turned on then no log entries are generated. The audit log contributes quite considerably to the growth of the repository if turned on. Therefore it is recommended to also configure the audit log purge job as a regular maintenance task.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a client lib folder that got deleted, then audit log won't help you much because it logs pages/dam creation/changes/deletion events.
You need to write your own listener for that, which will just make the repository grow.

I can only think of it happening on a dev like env as write access to /etc or /apps should be restricted on prod like envs.

Anyway to restore the content just reinstall the package through which the clientlib got installed.